# Authenticating multiple routes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple routes in my React app that I want to check to see if the logged in state is true before I let a user access the route. I have been trying to follow along on stack overflow answers like making a Private Route but all the answers only seem to show one route using this method. What is the best way to implement this with multiple routes? I have attempted it on my own but it does not really work because it only shows the item component and nothing else as I have specified that in PrivateRoute.

Here is my app.js:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import { LoggedInProvider } from "./contexts/LoggedIn";
import { ThemeProvider } from "./contexts/ThemeContext";
import SignIn from "./SignIn";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute"
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <LoggedInProvider>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <SignIn />} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/items" />
        </Switch>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </LoggedInProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my private route code that I don't want non logged in users accessing:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { LoggedInContext } from "./contexts/LoggedIn";
import Index from "./CRUD/index";
import NewItem from "./CRUD/NewItem";
import EditItem from "./CRUD/EditItem";
import GroupIndex from "./Groups/GroupIndex";
import NewGroup from "./Groups/NewGroup";

export default function PrivateRoute() {
  const { loggedIn } = useContext(LoggedInContext);
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/items"
        render={() => (loggedIn ? <Index /> : <Redirect to="/" />)}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/items/new"
        render={() => (loggedIn ? <NewItem /> : <Redirect to="/" />)}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/items/edit/:id"
        render={props =>
          loggedIn ? <EditItem {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
        }
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/groups"
        render={() => (loggedIn ? <GroupIndex /> : <Redirect to="/" />)}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/groups/new"
        render={() => (loggedIn ? <NewGroup /> : <Redirect to="/" />)}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Comment: I presume you have looked at the [Auth example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) in the docs? You seem to be bundling lots of routes into a single `PrivateRoute` component, the example demonstrates a way of implementing a reusable route that you then declare for each route you want to protect

Answer (score 0):

Look at below code and try to implement for yourself

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, render, ...rest }) => {

  const renderContent = props => {
    if (!isLogin) {
      return (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/auth",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      );
    }

    return typeof render === "function" ? (
      render(props)
    ) : (
      <Component {...props} />
    );
  };
  return <Route {...rest} render={renderContent} />;
};
```

then in app.js

```
      <PrivateRoute path="/items" component={/*Component Name*/}  />
```

Comment: A user could manipulate isLogin via the browser console, you can't do auth on the front end.

Comment: @ mancini0 its a sample code, not production!.I've mentioned ' try to implement for yourself'

Comment: Removing the -1 from this, this is actually the only answer that attempts to answer the question.

Comment: @ James, Thank you, I think it was a misunderstanding for others

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer this can be problematic as it is not very secure.

You may want to have a look at Koa or Express this will allow you to do server side routing which is more secure. You could also benefit from cleaner code by abstracting this from your front end.

There is a tutorial [here](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/scotch.io/tutorials/introduction-to-koa-the-future-of-express/amp)

Comment: There is no implementation of `LoggedInContext`, why do you presume the OP is doing authentication on the client? It's normal to protect routes on the client leveraging server state.

Comment: Apologies if I have jumped to a assumption but the OP did mention they did not want users that weren’t logged in to have access :)

Answer (score -1):

You should not do authorization on the front-end. On the front end, you can not prevent a malicious user from using the browser's javascript console or react-dev-tools to manipulate your auth related variables / component state.

Comment: There is no implementation of `LoggedInContext`, why do you presume the OP is doing authentication on the client? It's normal to protect routes on the client leveraging server state (I am not the downvoter btw).

Comment: Whatever the implementation is, it can be reassigned via the browser console.

Comment: you are confusing authentication with authorization, you might be able to fake authorization on the client-side but as soon as the client tries to do anything it e.g. fetch sensitive data from an API, it would immediately fail as the user isn't authenticated. There's nothing wrong with this approach, it's how many SPAs work.

Comment: @James, updated my answer to use the word 'authorization'. The OP is asking about restricting users from viewing already rendered (but weakly hidden) react components, i.e authorization.